# iTunes 12.3 doesn't recognize iPad 1 with iOS 5

Tags: itunes, ipad, macos, ios

I've upgraded my MacBook to El Capitan and my iTunes 12.3 doesn't recognize my iPad 1 with iOS 5 nor my iPhone 4s with iOS 9.1 any more.

I thought it was because my iPad 1 is too old and can't upgrade beyond iOS 5.1 but my iPhone 4 has the newer iOS 9.1.

So, any advice?

Answer (score -1):

Try using a different usb port and a different cable. 
Failing that, go to settings and reset 
Jo

Comment: What does "reset Jo" mean?